# Can not run jnlp files firefox

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I have written an applet in Java. The code is the following:

```
package welcomeapplet;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class WelcomeApplet extends  JApplet{

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Welcome to Java Programming", 25, 25);
    }
}
```

Following this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javase-jws.html) i have tried to run the program as shown in the following link when the error occurs [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=B72DE0EFE15750DA!110&cid=B72DE0EFE15750DA&group=0&authkey=!ABd9spO4S_Blris). Any ideas?

Comment: Well the prompt that says - 'Unable to launch the application.' has a button that reads.. 'Details`.  What are the details?  And please copy/paste the text, rather than upload another screenshot.